# how can i send facebook message using selenium webdriver

Tags: facebook, selenium, webdriver, message

I am able to login on facebook, able to open chat but unable to send any message
Below program code I have used:

//Login on FB >> **Working fine**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("******@gmail.com"); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("********");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_l']")).click();
```

// click on message icon >> **Working fine**

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_h']/li[1]/div/a/span")).click();
```

//click on friends name, to whom i want to send message >> **Working fine**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

//Send message    **>>>> here, i am not getting any response, code run without entered any message or error**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_552h _35li _n4k']")).sendKeys("Hiii");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);;
```

Comment: Debug your code step by step and see wheather elements are identified first

Comment: done,, i think the reason is, message area is not input box

Answer (score 3):

I have used this code, it works for me.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'_5rpu') and @role='combobox']")).sendKeys("hi"+Keys.ENTER);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: First, you need to identify text box locator and then use "driver.findElement(by.id()).sendkeys" method to send the text into the textbox, here Keys.ENTER will enter the text.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
@driver.get 'https://www.facebook.com/fname.lname?fref=none'
a = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//[@id="email"]').send_keys('aaa@gmail.com')
a = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="pass"]').send_keys('12345678')
a = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@value="Log In"]').click
sleep 5
a = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//a[@href="/messages/fname.lname" and @role="button"]').click
sleep 2;p 'This is Where I clicked/initiated the Send Message '
a = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//div[@class="_1ia"]/descendant::div[@class="_5rpu" and @role="textbox"]')
a.send_keys('Hi There') # This is where I entered the keys and Did Enter
a.send_keys:enter
```

[image: **Screen shot**]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.. but i never used "require 'selenium-webdriver'", could you please share any document to understand (as i am new in selenium) or any other method to solve it easily. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I did it in Ruby - you must have done it in Java .. thats all.
However use the Xpaths you should be able to send message like i did.

Comment: Xpath - 
'//div[@class="_1ia"]/descendant::div[@class="_5rpu" and @role="textbox"]'
----
And Send Keys Enter into the text box instead of click. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer since the `@role` has changed is :

```
WebElement sendmsg = driver
            .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1ia']/descendant::div[@class='_5rpu' and @role='combobox']"));
sendmsg.sendKeys("Just testing: using selenium webdriver" + Keys.ENTER);
```